# Japanese Hiragana Switched off for Input fields having type="number"

Tags: jquery, html

My application is used by Japanese clients, supports languages as English/Japanese.

The charset used in our html files are UTF-8.

When we are in Japanese language selected, the input field while entering Numbers, they need to switch off the Hiragana input mode.

Can it be possible to switch off Hiragana specifically for input fields with type="number" or not ?

We are using html, jquery for our application.

Check the difference below which is creating the issue:

Japanese Hiragana mode - ＠１２３１２３１３１３
English Mode - @1231231313

Comment: Why would you switch off UTF-8 for English texts? Most English characters occupy one byte in UTF-8.

Comment: Please see the 14 and 16 are much bigger in size and spacing in Hiragana mode of input.. that needs to be in english alphabets...

Comment: The shapes of the characters do not depend on encoding. Please describe your problem in concrete terms: what you did, including the relevant code, what was expected, what happened, and what you see as a problem there.

Comment: Please check the above edited question

Comment: Still no code. There is something in your code that makes the browser use different fonts in different situations. You have not described what these modes are and how they are taken into use.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store Japanese characters in a single byte. A single byte allows you a maximum of 256 possible values to be stored, that's nowhere near enough for a full Japanese alphabet. If you need to store arbitrary Japanese text, you need to support an encoding which supports Japanese, which is necessarily going use multiple bytes per character.

If you only need to support a specific subset of Japanese, e.g. only the characters "分時月年" etc, you can make this anything *you* want by storing some random byte in the database and map that to the character in some standard encoding as necessary. E.g.:

```
$intoDatabase = str_replace('時', chr(245), $string);

$fromDatabase = str_replace(chr(245), '時', $string);
```

Just make sure you're not using the byte `245` for other characters.

See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) and [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).